# Overlapping Keyboard on EditText and Button in fragments when soft keyboard appears when apply immersive mode

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment, android-softkeyboard

I want to use the soft keyboard, but it hides my EditText or buttons, I need it to scroll so the keyboard is not hiding it. It's working very well with Activity, but not working with Fragment.

I'm trying with this code:

```
 @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getActivity().getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_VISIBLE|WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE);
    }
```

And also try this code:

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getActivity().getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_PAN);
    }
```

Anybody got any suggestions for Fragment?

Comment: could you add screenshot?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this in the manifest of the particular activity

```
<activity
    android:name=".YourActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden|adjustResize/>
```

or in the oncreate of the activity

```
getActivity().getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_VISIBLE | WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE);
```

Comment: It's not working:

<activity
            android:name=".HomeActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
           android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden|adjustResize"
            android:label="@string/home_activity"
            android:screenOrientation="unspecified"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
</activity>